# How to have (cartesian) chart axis to scale using scientific notation?

Tags: javascript, extjs, web, extjs4.2

I have a `numeric` axis and I'd like it to display 1.6e10, 7e-10, 9.9e7, etc... It's currently scaling by incredibly small decimal numbers. `Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0.0e')` only displays 0.0e.

```
axes: [{
    type: 'numeric',
    position: 'left',
    title: {
        text: 'BER Level (log\u2081\u2080)', // 1_unicode and 0_unicode
        fontSize: '14px'
    },
    maximum: maxAxis,
    minimum: minAxis,
    grid: true,
    //renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0.0E'),
    label: {
        fontSize: '10px'
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.

In the `renderer`:

```
renderer: function(label, layout, lastLabel) {
    if (Math.abs(label) < 1.0) {
        var fl = Ext.util.Format.number(parseFloat(label.toString().split('e-')[0]), '0.0'); // returns String
        var sn = label.toString().split('e-')[1];
        var newLbl = Number(fl + 'e' + sn);
        if (!isNaN(newLbl)){
            label = newLbl;
        }
    }
    else {
        var fl = Ext.util.Format.number(parseFloat(label.toString().split('e')[0]), '0.0');
        var sn = label.toString().split('e')[1];
        var newLbl = Number(fl + 'e-' + sn);
        if (!isNaN(newLbl)){
            label = newLbl;
        }
    }
    return label;
},
```